# How to pass the data from modally presented ViewController to parent ViewController in swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift

I have two viewController from first view controller on button click i am showing another viewcontrller as present modally. I am not sure how to pass data from modally viewcontrller to parent viewcontroller.

Which is the best and clean way of doing this?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I am referring to both as parentVC and presentedVC for the answer. You can either pass a closure to presentedVC for it to execute later when it has data or use Delegate pattern to communicate to parentVC. Here are both approaches with pros and cons:

**1.Closures:**

This approach is useful if you just need to communicate the data to parentVC once from presentedVC.
First define a public closure in presentedVC like this. I am assuming here you need to send a dictionary of type [String: String] back to parentVC.

```
class PresentedVC : UIViewController {
   var closure : (([String: String]) -> Void)?
}
```

Now when you initialise the presentedVC and present it modally over parentVC , you need to specify what you need to do with the dictionary received. by parentVC like this:

```
//Initialise presentedVC

presentedVC.closure = { (dict) in
    //Make parentVC do something with the dictionary
}
//present it modally
```

After this you just need to execute this closure from presentedVC when you want to communicate back to parentVC. Keep in mind to properly use weak references to not create a retain cycle.

**2.Delegate Pattern:**

This approach is useful when there are a stream of events that want to be communicated back to parentVC instead of only one event like above.
First we need to define a protocol.Again, I am assuming here you need to send a dictionary of type [String: String] back to parentVC.

```
protocol PresentedVCCallbacks {
  func didStartDataGathering()
  func didCompleteDataGathering(data:[String: String])
}
```

You need parentVC to implement this protocol and define a delegate in your presentedVC when you present it:

```
//Initialise presentedVC
presentedVC.delegate = parentVC
//present it modally
```

Now just use this delegate to communicate with parentVC when needed:

```
//Lets assume we have a dictionary prepared at a point in presentedVC which needs to be sent to parentVC
delegate.didCompleteDataGathering(data:data)
```